# How to display same records in multiple drop down form database using PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have two drops down and I am able to display the records in one dropdown from a database. I am getting the second drop down list bank.I have to display same records in my second drop down but it is not displaying. If I delete first drop down then records are displaying in second drop down.I haven't change any think just copy paste the code.Would you help me in this?

```
  <?php
    $sql_emails="SELECT * FROM request";
    $result_emails = $conn->query($sql_emails);

    //first drop down 
  ?>
    <select class="selectpicker" name="first" data-live-search="true">
          <option style="color:#bbb;" value="" disabled selected>Select emails</option>
        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_emails)) { ?>
               <option value="<?php echo $row['Email'];?>"><?php echo $row['Email'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <?php mysqli_data_seek( $result_emails, 0 );  ?>
    <select class="selectpicker" name="second" data-live-search="true" id="learner-emails">
        <option style="color:#bbb;" value="" disabled selected>Select emails</option>
        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_emails)){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['Email'];?>"><?php echo $row['Email'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Amit, added name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysqli_data_seek( $result_emails, 0 ); use this before second dropdown
```

Comment: Cool! simple and easy.Thanks for help Mr.Nishant Saini

Comment: @NarendraVerma any time please marked it as an answer

Comment: Mr.Nishant, Can you explain me this and should I used your code every time if I need a result more than one drop down?

Comment: you can achieve this with two ways 1. mysqli_data_seek() function second 2. save data in array when you are getting it in first time. and use that array according to your requirement. In first case you have to restart query pointer from the position 0 , use has to use mysqli_data_seek() function

Answer (score 0):

Put the rows into an array at the beginning of your script.

```
$rows = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_emails))
    $rows[] = $row;
```

Then, on the html sections, loop over the array. You can loop over it as many times as you want. You can't do that with the query results.

```
<?php foreach($rows as $row):;?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['Email'];?>"><?php echo $row['Email'];?></option>
<?php endfor;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_array()` moves the pointer forward each time you call it. You need `mysqli_data_seek()` to set the pointer back to the start and then call `mysqli_fetch_array()` again.